# is it safe to rely on :after to add a colon to labels?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I want to add colons to all my `label` elements

```css
form label:after {
   content: " : ";
}
```

Any reason not to do this?

Comment: I think your floppy disk is going to save me. [I can't seem to fit the internet on my computer!](http://www.w3schools.com/downloadwww.htm)

Comment: @George Bailey: Of all the sites to find that kind of GIF in...

Comment: It's really [only IE7](http://caniuse.com/#search=after) that doesn't support it. Is it really that important for you to have a colon? If not, you're probably fine using the code that you posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of `radio` and `checkbox` inputs it's best practice to add the label after the input.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using some non-cross-browser CSS, maybe you should just use your editor's find/replace function.

Search for `</label>`

and replace with  `: </label>`

If you insist on doing this at runtime, then as previously mentioned, use either CSS with risks expected of IE.

or use some kind of jQuery, like `$('<span> : </span>').appendTo('label')`.

Answer (score 1):

Older browsers (e.g. IE 6) do not support this. Designers avoid using this feature because it is not cross-browser compatible. Unless you are sure all your users will be using a compatible browser, you might want to avoid that.

Comment: the only browser i am targeting that doesn't support this feature is IE7. and because it's just a colon, i am thinking it's not a huge deal if IE7 users don't see it.

Comment: Since it's just a colon, you may as well add it to your HTML.

Comment: my thinking was why add it 100+ times in html when you can specify it once in css

Comment: In that case, you have to pick your poison. Either add the colon multiple times or deal with inconsistencies between different browsers.

Comment: @qntmfred: You already add opening `<label>` and closing `</label>` tags 100+ times in your HTML. What's a single `:` character?

Comment: @BoltClock, I can see situations where adding the `:` character 100+ times can be tedious. However, I'd still recommend that if visual consistency is required. If not, then no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

It's unsupported in many older browsers. See the compatibility charts here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-after

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of taste.

Structurally, the colon probably has no reason to be in your html.  It's more of a style thing.  So it belongs on your css.

Question becomes, how important is it for you to see the colon on IE7.  Personally I wouldn't care too much.  IE7 usage is going down quickly (probably because win7 comes with IE8) and missing a colon will not hurt the ergonomics of the website.  So I would consider this **graceful degradation**.